# Run Python script from the Commandline using a certain Python installation

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

So far, I couldn't find out how to solve the following problem:

I have Python 3 installed under Windows 8.1. In addition to this Python installation, I have several other installations that came with programs such as QGIS and ArcGIS Pro. Those programs have their own Python installation with a Python exe shomewhere in their program folders.

Now I have a Python script that relies on some modules that are installed for QGIS Python. I want to run the script from the command line (or from within R). However, the script will be handled by my main Python installation that doesn't have the modules.

I tried to add some paths to the PATH and PYTHONPATH variables following instructions I found on the internet, but this only resulted in my Python IDE (Spyder) not starting anymore.

PATH:

```
C:\Users\Manuel\Python\Scripts\;C:\Users\Manuel\Python\;C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\JRE\bin;D:\x2go\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files;C:\Program Files\snap\bin;C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin;D:\Program_Files\gdal\bin;C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
```

PYTHONPATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs;C:\Users\Manuel;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14.16\apps\qgis\python\plugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14.16\apps\qgis\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14.16\apps\Python37
```

I also tried to replace "py" in the command prompt with C:\Programme\QGIS 3.14.16\bin\python3.exe, which also didn't work (Error: Access denied).

I tried [this](https://samashti.tech/how-to-use-qgis-spatial-algorithms-with-python-scripts/) tutorial to import the modules within python, bit it gives

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _core: Module not found
```

How can I tell the command prompt to use a specific Python installation in this single case (I want to use the other Python installation in every other case)?

Comment: In general this type of problem is solved by using virtual environments - see for instance: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ but it mght be helpful if you post your PATH and PYTHONPATH values.

Comment: Can the problem be caused by a space in the path? Try using escape characters https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/

Comment: Escaped the characters by placing every path in "": ```C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Programme\QGIS 3.14.16\bin\python3.exe" "D:\Dateien\Stud
ium_KIT\Master_GOEK\10_FS_Geooekologie\Multi-skalige_Fernerkundungsverfahren\Pro
jekt\py3\Export_Extent.py" "D:\Dateien\[...]\Projekt\dat\ortho2018_CIR_pays.jp2" "C:\
Users\Manuel\Desktop\Test\Shapefile.shp" "D:\Dateien\[...]\dat\Tile.tif"
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00004a30 (most recent call first):

C:\WINDOWS\system32>```

Answer (score 0):

I would do exact what you tried: "`I also tried to replace "py" in the command prompt with the entire path to the QGIS Python exe, which also didn't work (Error: Access denied).`"

But try to run it in a powershell with administrator privileges.

Comment: Access denied came up regardless of administrator privileges...

Comment: hmm, can you execute the specific python.exe **without arguments** from the command line?